# How to use multiple tokens DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making custom bots for a project and i'm trying to connect multiple tokens with differents clients so i can manage every clients one by one

My actual code is

```js
const tokens = ['token_1', 'token_2']
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

for(const token of tokens) {
const client = new Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(client.user.id)
});

client.login(token)
}
```

But imagine i want the second bot to send a message in a channel, how do i do this ?

Because if i put the `channel.send` in the for it will send the message with every bot, and i just want one bot, and i think `client[0]` does not work, if somebody can help it would be very cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example add a new array which will contain the clients

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const tokens = ['token_1', 'token_2'];
const clients = [];

for(const token of tokens) {
  const client = new Client();
  clients.push(client);

  client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(client.user.id);
  });

  client.login(token);
}
```

`clients[0]` will now returns the first client

Comment: However, using const client in the loop will not let you access it from the outside